# Picasso is not loading images on ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

Im trying to load images in a RecyclerView element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/innerrl"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerView adapter:

```
class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
lateinit var ctx:Context
lateinit var superHeroes:List<SuperHeroe>

fun RecyclerAdapter(listaHeroes:List<SuperHeroe>, ctx:Context){
    this.superHeroes=listaHeroes
    this.ctx=ctx
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.superhero_layout, parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = superHeroes.get(position)
    holder.bind(item, ctx)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return superHeroes.size
}

class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val superheroName = view.findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView
    val desc = view.findViewById(R.id.desc) as TextView
    val avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail) as ImageView
    fun bind(superhero:SuperHeroe, context: Context){
        superheroName.text = superhero.nombre
        desc.text = superhero.desc
        loadUrl(superhero.imagen, avatar, context)
    }
    fun loadUrl(url: String, target:ImageView, ctx:Context) {
        println(url)
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(url).into(target)
    }
}
}
```

The version of Picasso is:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

No images are loaded in the ImageView, but I've put a log in the loadUrl function, and if I click in the link, the image is shown in my browser. The rest of elements (Name, and description) are shown properly. What I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you define internet permission in the manifest?
like this,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

or also check Network security configuration:-

- Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled
  by default.

you can try with any options

**1.** try hitting the URL with "https://" instead of "http://"

**2.** Create file res/xml/network_security_config.xml -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
      <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

add this file in under application tag in manifest like this,

```
<application
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">    
</application>
```

**3.** use [usesCleartextTraffic](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

add this under application tag in manifest like this,

```
<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">    
</application>
```

Comment: I am declaring the permission, but the problem is not that. I found a similar question is SO. By adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to my manifest, the images are loading ok.

Comment: @Fustigador What `targetSdk` did you use?

Comment: Im using targetSdk=30

Comment: @Fustigador Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default. so, hitting the URL with "https://" instead of "http://" otherwise you need to add android:usesCleartextTraffic in manifest or add network security file in res/xml/network_security_config.xml. for more info checkout this ::  
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic

Comment: @Fustigador I edited my answer so anyone can get help from here